# VirtualBox Windows showing weird screen right after starting the Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox, windows-10

I am trying to create a virtual Windows using VirtualBox, and I have encountered a problem. I am following the [Wikipedia instructions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/VirtualBox/Setting_up_a_Virtual_Machine/Windows), and can solve every problem encountered so far until Step 19. After turning on the virtual machine, it shows me the following image, and nowhere does it give me an installation screen. Is this a known issue, and how should I fix it?

[image]

This may be helpful: [image]

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. It looks like a graphical driver problem. Any logs?
You can have a look [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=95867)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 rep, so I have to post this comment as an answer.

You don't have a virtual hard drive configured. You should have one on SATA port 0. Put the optical drive on SATA port 1.

I don't know if this is your problem though. I would have thought that windows setup would start without a hard drive.

Also, you have chosen Windows 32-bit as your OS. Is this correct?

If it is, there is no need to assign 8GB to your virtual machine. It wont use more than 4GB.